# windows 11, screen saver password comes back requiring reboot to fix

Tags: windows, screensaver

Windows 11 Pro 21 H2 22000.1042
There are many posts how to disable the screen saver password. I have read each. This is however an uncovered problem. The screen saver I use is blank screen. For some reason the password prompt comes back with no system changes, then a reboot removes it again. The registry change below does indeed remove the screen saver password, but it comes back randomly. Also I noticed that my user is denied access to the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] key. It has the correct values but the user has no access. I can use the admin user if needed. I use Outlook while working at home which may have some enterprise entanglements. I only use my Microsoft credential for Outlook and do not log in with it, though using Outlook may save a credential cache. I'm thinking a policy they push out may slip through somehow. If at work they push out a screen saver password policy to workstations. I would like to resolve this because, even when signed out from work via signout email and Outlook is closed, the screen saver password prompt sometimes comes back and I must reboot my machine to clear it.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\scrnsave.scr"
"LockScreenAutoLockActive"="0"
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="300"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"

ALSO

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"
```

Comment: What about just the vanilla screen saver to black,  If connected to Fingerprint, it will always properly ask for password (PIN or Fingerprint).

Comment: @john, don't see that option or don't know how. All I have is blank screen option for screen saver.

Comment: The settings are in User Accounts, Sign in Options.

Comment: Do you own this computer yourself? You mention doing work for others on it using Outlook. Yes, in order to access Outlook email the system can manage aspects of your computer.

Comment: @music2myear, yes I own it myself. I work at home and have Office 365 installed using a work login. When I log in it asks to set policies on my machine and I say no. I assume a credential is cached but does not show in windows credentials. If I don't change the work password I can open Outlook without subsequent password prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved for me from the following two pages:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-does-outlook-cause-my-screen-saver-to-start/02541ba9-04b2-41f6-8a8e-0fa18ca9d63e

https://www.slipstick.com/office-365/save-choice-stay-signed-apps/

It would be good to do a search for "BlockAADWorkplaceJoin" to educate oneself on the issue. For me the registry change below worked. Prior to that I displayed all credentials by going to Credential Manager through settings and removing any unknown Windows Credentials and anything implying Microsoft. I applied the registry change then rebooted.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WorkplaceJoin]
"BlockAADWorkplaceJoin"=dword:00000001
```